# Extending the custom formatting capabilities of built-in types

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

I have some rather awkward formatting requirements for `decimal` values. In a nutshell: display to two decimal places with a trailing space unless the third decimal is a 5, in which case display to three decimal places.

This formatting needs to be fairly flexible, too. Specifically, the trailing space will not always be desired, and a "½" may be preferred when the third decimal is a "5".

Examples:

- 1.13 would be displayed as "01.13 " with a space or "01.13" without it
- 1.315 would be displayed as "01.315" or "01.31½"

I need to use this logic consistently across otherwise unrelated pieces of UI. I have temporarily written it as a WPF value converter, but this is just for demonstration:

```
public sealed class PriceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is decimal))
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        var decimalValue = (decimal)value;
        var formattedDecimalValue = decimalValue.ToString("#0.000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var lastFormattedChar = formattedDecimalValue[formattedDecimalValue.Length - 1];

        switch (lastFormattedChar)
        {
            case '0':
                return formattedDecimalValue.Substring(0, formattedDecimalValue.Length - 1) + " ";
            case '5':
                return formattedDecimalValue.Substring(0, formattedDecimalValue.Length - 1) + "½";
            default:
                return formattedDecimalValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am now trying to extract this into a more fundamental building block I can use throughout my UI layer. My initial thought was a custom format provider which I could then use from a `Binding`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, FormatString=WHATEVER}"/>
```

The idea is that format string could be something like "#0.005" which indicates to only show the third decimal place if it's a 5, or "#0.00F" which attempts to represent the third decimal as a fraction. However, I was unable to find a means of using a specific format provider from a binding, which seems like a major limitation to me, but maybe I'm missing something...?

After more experimentation and investigation, I came to the conclusion that my only option is to define my own type:

```
public struct Price : IFormattable
```

This type would encapsulate the extra formatting capabilities I require. However, now I have another conundrum: in my `ToString` implementation, how can I leverage the existing formatting capabilities of `decimal.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)` without interfering with my own? It seems like this would be pretty darn messy, and it's causing me to lean towards a more limited solution of just defining "G" (two or three decimal places, no trailing space) and "S" (same as "G", but with trailing space if necessary) formats for my `Price` structure.

Can anyone tell me whether there's a way for me to do this kind of custom formatting capability without too much hassle?

Comment: Would some unique prefix for formatting string work to distinguish your custom and default formatting? Like "&#0.00" for custom and "#0.00" for default (if first character special - use custom...)

Comment: @Alexei: that would work only if I wanted to take full ownership of the formatting code, but I'd prefer to delegate to built-in formatting and then supplement with my own bits and pieces. Otherwise, I'd have to re-implement an awful lot of built-in functionality.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438089/how-to-delegate-to-default-format-provider

Comment: @amald: thanks, but that doesn't help in my scenario. I can't just remove parts of the format string because they're subsequently important to my specific formatting rules. And I can't assume that certain characters are even my indicators, because custom formatting allows for literal strings to appear within the format string. Hence, I'd need to parse the format string unless there's some way of getting at a parsed representation of it.

Comment: please avoid using "sealed" or "final", consider that your source code, sooner or later, may be extended by hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx for more details.

```
// "01.13 " or "01.13". Standard formatting applied: $123.45
// "01.315" or "01.31½". Standard formatting applied: $123.45

public class Test
{
    void Main()
    {
        decimal number1 = 1.13M;
        decimal number2 = 1.315M;

        string output1 = String.Format(new CustomNumberFormat(),
                                 "\"{0:G}\" or \"{0:S}\". Standard formatting applied: {1:C2}",
                                 number1, 123.45);
        Console.WriteLine(output1);

        string output2 = String.Format(new CustomNumberFormat(),
                                 "\"{0:G}\" or \"{0:S}\". Standard formatting applied: {1:C2}",
                                 number2, 123.45);
        Console.WriteLine(output2);
    }
}

public class CustomNumberFormat : System.IFormatProvider, System.ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Format(string fmt, object arg, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        // Provide default formatting if arg is not a decimal. 
        if (arg.GetType() != typeof(decimal))
            try
            {
                return HandleOtherFormats(fmt, arg);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                throw new FormatException(String.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid.", fmt), e);
            }

        // Provide default formatting for unsupported format strings. 
        string ufmt = fmt.ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (!(ufmt == "G" || ufmt == "S"))
            try
            {
                return HandleOtherFormats(fmt, arg);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                throw new FormatException(String.Format("The format of '{0}' is invalid.", fmt), e);
            }

        // Convert argument to a string. 
        string result = ((decimal)arg).ToString("0#.000");

        if (ufmt == "G")
        {
            var lastFormattedChar = result[result.Length - 1];
            switch (lastFormattedChar)
            {
                case '0':
                    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1) + " ";
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }
        else if (ufmt == "S")
        {
            var lastFormattedChar = result[result.Length - 1];
            switch (lastFormattedChar)
            {
                case '0':
                    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
                    break;
                case '5':
                    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1) + "½";
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    private string HandleOtherFormats(string format, object arg)
    {
        if (arg is System.IFormattable)
            return ((System.IFormattable)arg).ToString(format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        else if (arg != null)
            return arg.ToString();
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed the point of my question :) My idea around `"G"`/`"S"` was as a fallback plan - one that I took with a much simpler implementation than what you suggest (`IFormattable` was key, and ensured it worked from bindings too, whereas your suggestion won't without converters). What I actually wanted was to support custom formatting, not standard formatting. See the examples earlier in my question such as `"#0.005"`. When you try and supplement built-in custom formatting with your own, you wind up having to reimplement a lot of stuff that you'd much rather delegate to.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in your format provider as the `parameter` argument in your `IValueConverter.Convert` implementation:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource PriceConverter}, ConverterParameter=#0.00F"/>
```

Then, inside your converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string formatString = parameter as string;

    if(formatString != null)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
    else
    {
        // Whatever you want to do here
    }

}
```